# How do Google App Engine Task Queues work?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, queue, task

I'm confused about Task execution using queues.  I've read the documentation and I thought I understood bucket_size and rate, but when I send 20 Tasks to a queue set to 5/h, size 5, all 20 Tasks execute one after the other as quickly as possible, finishing in less than 1 minute.

```
deferred.defer(spam.cookEggs, 
               egg_keys, 
               _queue="tortoise")  

- name: tortoise
  rate: 5/h  
  bucket_size: 5
```

What I want is whether I create 10 or 100 Tasks, I only want 5 of them to run per hour.  So it would take 20 Tasks approximately 4 hours to complete.  I want their execution spread out.

#### UPDATE

The problem was I assumed that when running locally, that Task execution rate rules were followed, but that is not the case.  You cannot test execution rates locally.  When I deployed to production, the rate and bucket size I had set executed as I expected.

Comment: Does this help you at all? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#The_Schedule_Format

Comment: So you're saying I should be using Scheduled Tasks instead?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you that one way or another. I've only recently begun working with the app engine, so I heard "tasks" then I heard "per hour" and thought scheduled tasks :] I think it's worth a design consideration -- especially if nothing else works..

Comment: Is this in production, or the dev_appserver? I don't believe the dev_appserver respects execution rates.

Comment: It's on dev_appserver, and I believe you're right.  I created a "test" version for production and it executed as expected.

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is preferred to deleting in situations like this.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer and mark it as accepted. So other SO users can tell you're question has already been answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execution rates are not honored by the app_devserver. This issue should not occur in production.

*[Answer discovered by Nick Johnson and/or question author; posting here as community wiki so we have something that can get marked accepted]*

Answer (score -1):

You want to set `bucket_size` to 1, or else you'll have "bursts" of queued activity like you saw there.

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html):

> bucket_size
>
> Limits the burstiness of the queue's
>   processing, i.e. a higher bucket size
>   allows bigger spikes in the queue's
>   execution rate. For example, consider
>   a queue with a rate of 5/s and a
>   bucket size of 10. If that queue has
>   been inactive for some time (allowing
>   its "token bucket" to fill up), and 20
>   tasks are suddenly enqueued, it will
>   be allowed to execute 10 tasks
>   immediately. But in the following
>   second, only 5 more tasks will be able
>   to be executed because the token
>   bucket has been depleted and is
>   refilling at the specified rate of
>   5/s.

Comment: I did read that, several times, and to me that says that if I have rate at 5/h, and a bucket size of 5, then 5 Tasks will run immediately, but then it will take an hour for 5 more tokens to fill up the bucket, so 5 more Tasks would run over that hour, and so on.  But what I am seeing is all 20 Tasks are running immediately, one after the other.

Comment: And when I set bucket_size to 1, it executes at the same rate as far as I can tell.